# Guidelines for setting haggle test difficulty when using the tracking money option?

Tags: treasure, optional-rules, wfrp-4e

I have been running a game of WFRP 4e and my players haven't really been enjoying tracking money much so I was thinking of switching to the optional tracking money rule on page 290 of the rule book.

> Where some groups like to track every penny closely, perhaps
> even using chits or fantasy coins to represent in-game coins,
> others prefer to ignore all fiscal book-keeping. The game
> rules assume you are counting every coin, but if you wish to
> simplify money, you can do so using your Status. If an item
> costs less than your
> Status level — so if you have a
> Status of
> Silver 2, any item costing 2 silver shillings or less — you are
> assumed to be able to buy as much as needed of that item.
> Beyond that, you can buy a maximum of one item a day that
> costs more with a Haggle Test, with the difficulty set by the
> GM according to the cost of the item and the local markets.

My problem is that according to the rules only a gold tier character can reasonably afford a main gauche let alone other weapons so my players will need to make haggling tests however I couldn't find a guideline for haggle tests when using this system.(And the regular haggle rules woul not be appropriate on the grounds that the most you can negotiate is a %50 off) So what I wish to ask is Are there any guidelines somewhere for setting haggle difficulty and if not what are the rules you use on your table?